# How to keep my dog from circumventing her massive e-collar?

Tags: dogs, safety, injury

My dog (10 month old Collie mix) recently had to have stitches on the bottom of her right hind foot. The vet provided an e-collar (aka "cone of shame"), appropriately sized, but she is a rubber puppy and managed to get to the bottom of her foot and pull out the stitches.

She had new stitches put in, and we got her a larger e-collar - she is about 35 lb (18 kg), and the picture on this e-collar shows a Great Dane.

Today is the third day with this new collar, but she appears close to getting her foot inside of this one too! It is the largest size that my pet store sells, and is already large enough that she can just barely get to her food/water bowl.

The vet has instructed us to leave the stitches uncovered so that the wound will heal appropriately. **What strategies/tactics can I use to keep her from getting to the stitches, in addition to the massive e-collar?**

Comment: Some thoughts that aren't enough for an actual answer: to pull the stitches, the hind leg must be bent forward enough to be reached by her snout. If you could craft a pillow or padding that could be tied around her tummy, it could keep her from moving her leg into a position suitable for nibbling. But that would also be very uncomfortable for her while lying down...